# Add temporary property to list of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have 3 models

```
public class Payroll
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int PayCategoryID { get; set; }

    public virtual PayCategory PayCategory { get; set; }
}
```

this one:

```
public class PayCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string PayScenario { get; set; }

    public int PayGroupID { get; set; }

    public virtual PayGroup PayGroup { get; set; }
}
```

and this one:

```
public class PayGroup 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string EntryType { get; set; }

}
```

If I create a List of Payroll I will only get a list of Payroll objects with 4 properties each. 
I want a list of , where each Payroll object will have the fields
       Date, PayScenario, Label, Description, and EntryType. I know these can be easily obtained by

```
    Payroll.PayCategory.PayScenario
    Payroll.PayCategory.PayGroup.Label
```

etc.

But I am exporting these to an excel document using this generic method:

```
      public static void Export(List<T> data, string name, Controller controller) 
    {
        XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(name);
        worksheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(data); 
        controller.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheet.sheet";
        controller.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", String.Format(@"attachment;filename={0}.xlsx", name.Replace(" ", "_")));
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
            memoryStream.WriteTo(controller.Response.OutputStream);
            memoryStream.Close();
        }
        controller.Response.End();

    }
```

I call from controller like this:

```
    public ActionResult ExportData()
    {
        var payrolls = (List<Payroll>)Session["payrolls"];
        ExportToExel<Payroll>.Export(payrolls, "Payroll", this);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

And the results of course give me a simple table with only the value Date in it, (plus some other trash columns like System [...] PayCategory)

Ultimately, I want the properties of these 3 models to be merged (excluding ID's) to give me a single list that I can pass on to the ExportData method. As in, is there a way to add a column to a list of objects? Something similar to

```
        for(int i = 1; i<payrolls.Count; i++)
              payrolls[i].Add.(payrolls[i].PayCategory.PayScenario);
```

which of course, doesn't work.
Please don't ask why I don't simply have one model instead of these 3. It's not an option unless I want to hard code values.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should create new class for this usage? Next you can simply map(by AutoMapper for example) Payroll class with its references to new created class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can import Linq, you can do something like:

```
var payrolls = from aPayroll in (List<Payroll>)Session["payrolls"]
               select new {
                    Date = aPayroll.Date,
                    PayScenario = aPayroll.PayCategory.PayScenario,
                    Label = aPayroll.PayGroup.Label,
                    Description = aPayroll.PayGroup.Description,
                    EntryType = aPayroll.PayGroup.EntryType
               };
```

That would create an anonymous type with the five properties you want.

Assuming you're using ClosedXML, you should also be able to [create a DataTable and send it directly to a worksheet.](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Adding%20DataTable%20as%20Worksheet&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: I took too long writing this, @user1698727 is right

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is an "Anonymous Object".

Example usage:

```
var anonymousObject = new
                    {
                        ID = payrollObj.Id,
                        // other payroll properties
                        PayScenario = payrollObj.PayCategory.PayScenario
                        // other extended properties
                    };
```

Here's an article about them
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/anonymous-types-in-C-Sharp/

The suggestion here is to create a new anonymous object within your loop and pass that onto your excel function instead of the original payrollObject.

Comment: How can I declare the excel function?         public static void Export(List<T> data, string name, Controller controller), the List<T> won't let the anon object go through compilation

Comment: nvm I got it with List<dynamic>